PowerPivot - DAX Formula - How to calculate just the monthly sales orders total
I'm attempting to calculate the monthly sales orders total using DAX in PowerPivot. I am able to calculate the running total (YTD), but am stuck on how to just capture the monthly total. I'm currently using the below formula for the running total:
Actual Sales Orders column:
=
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Sales Orders'[Qty]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Date Table'[Date]),
        ISONORAFTER('Date Table'[Date],MAX('Sales Orders'[Ship Date]),DESC)
    )
)

The [Date] is a daily occurrence, as is the [Ship Date]. Please let me know if I am missing something that would help.
For example, for the month of July, I should see 60 in the field for the Part#, but it's returning the running YTD total of 420.

Also, here are the tables being used:


Can you add some data please.?
